# Hybrid parallelization: 'Making only 'my_id ==0' process executes openMP calls' possible?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, mpi, openmp

I'm very new to Hybrid parallel coding, so I'm wondering this kind of concept is possible, and whether it will cause bad efficiency of parallelization.

Let's say that I need `A` routine and `B` routine. `A` is quite difficult to parallelize with MPI, while `B` is relatively straightforward to MPI. Since I want this code to be scalable to some extent, I'm going to exploit as much MPI parallelization as I can.

I'm getting the concepts of `thread` and `process` very roughly, I suppose the numbers of `total threads` to be `n_threads x n_process`.

```
program Hybrid
  use MPI
  use OMP_LIB

  call MPI_INIT ( ierr )
* call MPI_COMM_SIZE ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, n_process, ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_RANK ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr )
  ...
* call omp_set_num_threads ( n_threads )
  ...
  call MPI_FINALIZE ( ierr )

end program
```

So in above example, `total threads` becomes `n_threads x n_process` in my understanding (I'm not sure whether I'm using the word `total threads` properly, though). The asterisks(*) are just for making it easy to find `n_threads` and `n_process`.

My serial version of code looks like,

```
program Serial

  do i = 1, time_steps
    call A
    call B
  enddo

end program
```

Both `A` and `B` needs a global view of array.

MPI parallelized `B` routine, `B_MPI`, starts with some `MPI_ScatterV` to distribute its global information into sub processes, and it ends with `MPI_GatherV` to recover all global view, and only the 'my_id == 0' process holds this global view.

While I want `A` to be parallelized with OpenMP, I don't want to activate too many `threads`, so want only 'my_id == 0' process calls OpenMP calls, makes folks of OpenMP threads like below.

```
program
  use MPI
  use OMP_LIB

  call MPI_INIT ( ierr )
* call MPI_COMM_SIZE ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, n_process, ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_RANK ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr )

  ...

  do i = 1, time_steps

    if (my_id == 0) then
*     call A_OMP   ! 'call omp_set_num_threads ( n_threads ) ' inside the 'A_OMP'
    endif

    call B_MPI     ! Starts with 'MPI_ScatterV', ends with 'MPI_GatherV'

  enddo

end program
```

So in this way, only invoking OpenMP calls inside 'my_id == 0', I want to make the `total threads` to be like `n_process + n_threads`, rather than `n_process x n_threads`.

To be honest, I'm not very sure how `threads` are folked if they're mixed with MPI. I want to make it sure whether above kind of picture is possible, and will be efficient.

Thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issue with this in principle, although note that using your terminology total_threads = n_threads + n_process - 1. If you had 10 physical CPU-cores and wanted to use 4 OpenMP threads, then you would have to launch 7 MPI processes. MPI rank 0 would only create 3 *additional* threads in the parallel region - the other thread, OpenMP thread 0, is just the original MPI process.

The issue in practice is that to get this to work efficiently you'll need to make sure that the 7 MPI processes and 3 additional OpenMP threads are scheduled appropriately at runtime, i.e. bound to the appropriate CPU cores. This might require a combination of both MPI and OpenMP affinity settings that will need to work together appropriately. Of course, you can never efficiently use more OpenMP threads than you have cores in a node as all the threads must run on the same physical computer as MPI rank 0.